# Joomla 3 category blog article override

Tags: joomla, joomla3.0

Im trying to override the article layout for articles showing in the category blog layout. I have overriden the blog.php file from the folder components/com_content/views/category/tmpl into mytemplate/html/com_content/category, but this only overrides the category blog layout, not the layout of the actual articles.

The bit i need to override is the bit that loads inside here,

```
<article class="leading-<?php echo $leadingcount; ?><?php echo $item->state == 0 ? ' system-unpublished' : null; ?>" itemprop="blogPost" itemscope itemtype="http://schema.org/BlogPosting">
  <?php
    $this->item = & $item;
    echo $this->loadTemplate('item');
  ?>
</article>
```

Any ideas how to do this without overriding every article on the site.

Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you should override this file:

```
components/com_content/views/category/tmpl/blog_item.php
```

Read More:

[Customize Your Joomla Templates by Learning Overrides](https://www.joomlashack.com/blog/joomla-templates/1067-customize-your-joomla-templates-by-learning-overrides)

Answer (score 1):

You need to create another template over for the single article view. Place files to override from here:

```
components/com_content/views/articles/tmpl/
```

In here:

```
templates/myTemplate/html/com_content/article/
```

You can keep the names the same and every Article will use this template  to render, or you can rename and manually assign the template to individual articles as needed.

Some links on the details on template overrides.

http://docs.joomla.org/How_to_override_the_output_from_the_Joomla!_core
http://docs.joomla.org/Understanding_Output_Overrides
http://docs.joomla.org/Layout_Overrides_in_Joomla

Answer (score 0):

Try to override the following tmpl files :"category/blog_item.php", "category/default_articles.php" and "article/default.php"

Comment: The problem is that, in the latest version (3.3), I created a category blog, but the code seems to be generated somewhere else. I looked for it in the directory `category/*`, but there is no code that I can change in order to change the article title style from H2 to H4.